# how i can appear multiple well in a list view

Tags: gui-design, ux-designer, android

I work on a mobile application. I have to post a list. The client wants to display several information about each item. This will not give a good appearance of the interface. I am looking for a solution that can complement the customer. This is a draw that can explain the demand.
The circle that contains a "?" The symbol means a pop-up window.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Think about what information is part of one item. Check with your users what information is most important. Show this in the list. Show the other information only after the user clicks on the item.

Give your items more 'breathing room'. Increase the margins. It will give your list a much clearer look. When text is too long, truncate it.

See the image below. The items have a lot of room and show only three things (title, subtitle and date). The rest will be visible when users click the item.

[image]